# Handling HTTPS certificates with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, ssl, https, nsurlsession

I want to learn how to deal with `SSL` certificates and `HTTPS` requests in `iOS`, and I've read [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-https-certificate-handling-to-protect-your-ios-app/) tutorial to try to get the basics but, since it uses `NSURLConnection` and it became deprecated in `iOS 9`, I've been looking for an example/tutorial of this process using `NSURLSession`, but I didn't find any.

I'd appreciate some guidence for this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're trying to do? Launch an HTTPS request? Pin to a specific server certificate? Pin to a specific certificate authority?